# Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [int]; For input string: "batch_cancel"

Tags: spring, gradle, url, numberformatexception, http-status-code-400

I'm getting the following error:

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for
> /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Mon Dec 21 10:30:26 GMT 2020 There was an unexpected error (type=Bad
> Request, status=400). Failed to convert value of type
> [java.lang.String] to required type [int]; nested exception is
> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "batch_cancel"

This happens when trying to call the following method via URL:

```
@Override   
@RequestMapping(path = {"/batch_cancel"}, method=POST)  
public ResponseEntity<String> notificationBatchCancel()
```

The method at this stage takes no parameters and simply returns null, whilst printing out a message to console to show that it works (Obviously, it doesn't").

I don't get why there is a String to int conversion error on the path.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I've seen similar posts referring to the parameters, but in this case, there aren't any (yet). Other methods in the class seem to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind...

I changed from POST to GET and now works. Not ideal, but it will do for now!